# Couchdb _replicate endpoint doesn't accept port 443

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

I am running

```
curl -XPOST "$COUCHDB_ADMIN_URL/_replicate"  \
  -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
  -d "{\"source\": \"$COUCHDB_ADMIN_URL/alice-db\", \"target\": \"http://bob:p%40ssword@localhost:5984/alice-db-copy-for-bob\", \"create_target\": true }"
```

from https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/2892 with my credentials@url:443

Normally the Port for the couchdb instance is 5984, but I am using docker to run a service which doesn't expose 5984 only 80/443 and routes traffic internally so I don't have access to 5984 from outside.

When I try to replicate on the endpoint 5984 I get req_timeout, and as soon as I change to 443 which is where I can access the database under _utils I get

```
{"error":"invalid_json","reason":"{error,{1,invalid_json}}"}
```

Is there a way to go around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service was running on a docker container so it had a different IP, I checked

```
sudo docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' CONTAINERID
```

which gave me the IP address I needed, and then I used the port 5984 which is normally the couchDB port.